# MVC Routing Redirection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a webservice project that is being expanded to host multiple APIs instead of just one, so I wanted to cleanup the routes without breaking the old version.  The main API used to sit off of a controller named API and accept parameters like this:

```
api/{language}/{action}/{*parameters}
```

Now, I have an Area named API that is going to house each of the APIs in their own controller and the route will look like this:

```
api/{controller}/{language}/{action}
```

I still need the old route to be usable for legacy apps already using the old route, I was hoping just to be able to create a 2nd "legacy" route that would catch the old pathing and use the new controller.  I tried this but it only worked then with the new location and the ikd one returned a 404.

```
api/{language}/{action}/{*parameters}",
new { controller = "api1", action = "Index", language = "json" }
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  I tried RouteMagic but it didn't seem to work.  Maybe I set the redirect up wrong though.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - anything matching the second route will also match the first. How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out after getting a sandwhich...just needed to add route constraints so that the old version would not catch on the new route format:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
       "API_default",
       "api/{controller}/{language}/{action}",
       new { controller = "api1", action = "Index", language = "json" },
       new { language = "json|xml" }
   );

   routes.MapRoute(
       "API_legacy",
       "api/{language}/{action}/{*parameters}",
       new { controller = "api1", action = "Index", language = "json", parameters = UrlParameter.Optional },
       new { language = "json|xml" }
   );
```